# Take picture and save it to camera roll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I want to take a picture in my Android app and save it to the camera roll. I'm using `CameraRoll` and `RNCamera` but the image is nowhere to be seen in the camera roll.

The function is:

```
...
import { RNCamera } from "react-native-camera";
import { CameraRoll } from "react-native";
...

async _takePicture() {
    const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({
      quality: 1.0,
      base64: true,
      orientation: "portrait",
      fixOrientation: true
    });
    CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri, "photo");
  }
...
```

**Edit:**
I solved it by adding

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
              PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
              {
                title: 'My App Storage Permission',
                message: 'My App needs access to your storage ' +
                  'so you can save your photos',
              },
            );
```

after `CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri, "photo");`

Comment: Have you setted write permission?

Comment: Indeed. I just added an edit.

Comment: Cool, this is one of my favorite features of react native, that it makes it super simple to ask for user permissions compared to the Java implementation :-)